# Draw Vector Operations

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I would like to draw something like this:

[image]
[image]

I need to display a lot of combinations of such operations, so my question - is there any effective way to draw such vector operations?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. It is much more likely that people will help you if you show that you have at least tried to do something yourself rather than expect some one to do everything for you. I would start by looking at the [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) manual.

Comment: @Andrew: The link to the TikZ package on CTAN is https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should get you started:

[image]

It is drawn using [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz). It would be better to automate this a little more...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

  \tikzset{% define the style of the nodes for drawing the squares
     mysquare/.style ={shape=rectangle, draw=black!40,thick, top color=white,
                       bottom color=#1, drop shadow,
     }
  }
  \begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace*{20mm}}c}% put inside a table to compactify the image
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,...,3} {% loop over the three rows
       \node[mysquare=yellow!30] at (0,-\x) {$A_\x$};
       \node at (1,-\x) {$+$};
       \node[mysquare=green!40] at (2,-\x) {$B_\x$};
       \node at (3,-\x) {$=$};
       \node[mysquare=red!50] at (4,-\x) {$C_\x$};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
  &
  \begin{tikzpicture}% use positioning to put the boxes together
    \foreach \letter/\col/\x in {A/yellow!30/0, B/green!40/2, C/red!50/4} {
      \node[mysquare=\col] (\letter 0) at (\x,0){$\letter_0$};
      \node[below=-1pt of \letter 0,mysquare=\col] (\letter 1) {$\letter_1$};
      \node[below=-1pt of \letter 1,mysquare=\col] (\letter 2) {$\letter_2$};
      \node[below=-1pt of \letter 2,mysquare=\col] (\letter 3) {$\letter_3$};
    }
    \node at (1,-0.8) {$+$};% place + and = by hand
    \node at (3,-0.8) {$=$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a (not very elegant) PSTricks solution with the following syntax for the macro:

```
\VectorOp[<index in bottom row>]{<number of rows>}
```

Now to the code the and output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pst-slpe}
\usepackage{xfp}

% parameters
\def\paraA{0.70}
\def\paraB{0.36}
\def\paraC{0.54}
\def\paraD{0.28}
% macros for structuring the code
\newcommand*\distA[2]{\fpeval{\paraA*(#1-1)+\paraB*#2}}
\newcommand*\distB[2]{\fpeval{(0.5*\paraC*(#2-1)+\paraD)*#1}}
% vector operations
\def\vectorOp[#1]#2{%
\begin{pspicture}(\distA{5}{2},\distB{2}{#2})
\psset{fillstyle = slope, slopeangle = 90, slopeend = white}
  \multido{\r = \paraD+\paraC, \i = #1+-1}{#2}{%
    \rput(\distA{1}{1},\r){\psframebox[slopebegin = yellow!50]{$A_{\i}$}}
    \rput(\distA{3}{1},\r){\psframebox[slopebegin = green!50]{$B_{\i}$}}
    \rput(\distA{5}{1},\r){\psframebox[slopebegin = orange]{$C_{\i}$}}}
  \rput(\distA{2}{1},\distB{1}{#2}){$+$}
  \rput(\distA{4}{1},\distB{1}{#2}){$=$}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  &\vectorOp[0]{1}\\[0.5ex]
  &\vectorOp[1]{1}\\[0.5ex]
  &\vectorOp[2]{1}\\[0.5ex]
  &\vectorOp[3]{1}\\[4ex]
  &\vectorOp[3]{4}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]